# Custom page Error doesn't work. (in production always return code 500)

Tags: twig, symfony5

So i'm working on a project and i wanted to make custom error page like 404 500 ...

So i read on symfony documentation that all i have to do is c`omposer twig-pack`, then add the `error404.html.twig` in this tree directory `\templates\bundles\TwigBundle\Exception`. To finish I have to change my .env in prod to see my beauty error page.

But when i try to type a wrong url expecting to get my 404, instead, i got a 500 (the basic error page from symfony).

I checked my logs and i found that i got this Critical Error :

```
[2021-07-14T08:35:15.194689+00:00] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET https://micro59/dejifosd"" at C:\wamp\www\Projects\micropro\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php line 136 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET https://micro59/dejifosd\" at C:\\wamp\\www\\Projects\\micropro\\vendor\\symfony\\http-kernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener.php:136)\n[previous exception] [object] (Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/dejifosd/\". at C:\\wamp\\www\\Projects\\micropro\\vendor\\symfony\\routing\\Matcher\\Dumper\\CompiledUrlMatcherTrait.php:70)"} []
[2021-07-14T08:35:15.229712+00:00] php.CRITICAL: Uncaught Error: Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension::getPath(): Argument #1 ($name) must be of type string, null given, called in C:\wamp\www\Projects\micropro\var\cache\prod\twig\d5\d51256555fdd9ed9db40150aba9ba2f8325c04e57ae45e60937191a29447ddd2.php on line 37 {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Symfony\\Bridge\\Twig\\Extension\\RoutingExtension::getPath(): Argument #1 ($name) must be of type string, null given, called in C:\\wamp\\www\\Projects\\micropro\\var\\cache\\prod\\twig\\d5\\d51256555fdd9ed9db40150aba9ba2f8325c04e57ae45e60937191a29447ddd2.php on line 37 at C:\\wamp\\www\\Projects\\micropro\\vendor\\symfony\\twig-bridge\\Extension\\RoutingExtension.php:46)"} []
[2021-07-14T08:35:15.232242+00:00] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception TypeError: "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension::getPath(): Argument #1 ($name) must be of type string, null given, called in C:\wamp\www\Projects\micropro\var\cache\prod\twig\d5\d51256555fdd9ed9db40150aba9ba2f8325c04e57ae45e60937191a29447ddd2.php on line 37" at C:\wamp\www\Projects\micropro\vendor\symfony\twig-bridge\Extension\RoutingExtension.php line 46 {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Symfony\\Bridge\\Twig\\Extension\\RoutingExtension::getPath(): Argument #1 ($name) must be of type string, null given, called in C:\\wamp\\www\\Projects\\micropro\\var\\cache\\prod\\twig\\d5\\d51256555fdd9ed9db40150aba9ba2f8325c04e57ae45e60937191a29447ddd2.php on line 37 at C:\\wamp\\www\\Projects\\micropro\\vendor\\symfony\\twig-bridge\\Extension\\RoutingExtension.php:46)"} []
```

Aaaaaaaand thats where i'm stuck. I try many things (Composer update, Clear cache...) but nothing change. If someone would have the kindness to help me that would be much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class & method in the error message, `RoutingExtension::getPath()`, defines a Twig function - [path()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path). Your error404.html.twig file uses that function but doesn't have the required first parameter ('name', the route name) - or the value that is being passed to it, is null.

---

[How to Customize Error Pages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#example-404-error-template) has a simple error-page template, and has a sample path/route-name `{{ path('homepage') }}`.

You can get a list of the routes you have available so far with `bin/console debug:router` - it must be known to the framework, or it will throw an error about an unknown route.

It also has a .yaml you can use to make the error pages available in development (your controller is fine, this would be a bit cleaner and easier - and would only be available in development because of the path within the config/ directory is only read when your APP_ENV variable is 'dev').

If you have not already, `composer require debug-pack` and any errors - including on your '/error404' page will show a 'big friendly error page', should also add a lot of useful information - often including showing the file and line in the twig template.

In this particular instance, because of the type of error, it can't as it's deep in the Twig library internals (and comes from the PHP type-system, not an error found directly by Symfony or Twig) - but it will have a link in the stack trace to show the compiled twig template (in a randomly named file in ./var/cache/dev/twig/../.......php) and it shows where in the twig template it's calling the `->getPath();` - so you'll be able to track it down in the actual .twig file (it adds comments for the line number within the template to help).

Comment: Ok so based on your answer here what I did:
I created a new file ```ErrorController.php```
Then added a method called ```show()``` that return a render of my error404 template.
And i also added to my method an Annotation Route : ```@Route("/error404", name="app_error")```

But nothing change i still have this error. Also i made progress now i know my template is called correctly i just need to fix this $name.

Sorry if i'm too dumb to understand simple things but i'm not use to symfony yet, still learning.

Comment: Thank you that helped me a lot.